# Use of SQLAlchemy vs use of stored procedures

Tags: sql, performance, stored-procedures, sqlalchemy

What is performance-wise better: to query a database via SQLAlchemy API [`product.sales[0].location`] or to write a stored procedure in a database and call it in python.